# Push Windows Updates?

Tags: windows-update, update, patch-management

Is there a method or software that will allow the ability to push windows updates to clients in an non-active directory environment?

WSUS is not an option for the situation as it doesn't have the ability to push the updates to the clients, only for the clients to pull updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://wpkg.org/Category:Silent_installers_for_Windows_Hotfixes
wpkg "pulls" hotfixes as well, but you can let windows run wpkg  whenever you want.

Comment: WPKG rocks in a non AD enviroment!

Answer (score 1):

Also pull, but [this is a script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387102(VS.85).aspx) that will search for, download and immediately install updates when run - which I sometimes use for Core servers. Executing this remotely is pretty close to a "push".

Answer (score 0):

You could force the scan of new updates using `wuauclt /detectnow`.

I don't think it is possible to push the updates, since they are retrieved via http protocol by a service running with Administrator privileges; a system to "push" something into that service from an external source would be a good entry point for malware.

Answer (score 0):

A logon batch file inside your startup folder pointing to an offline version of wsus setup to run invisible from the current user.

I run a similar setup to some PC's which for security reasons aren't connected directly to the network.

http://download.wsusoffline.net/

I update it every Wednesday and by Thursday the few computers have all the newest patches.